ubuntu server 22.04 not upgrading to 24.04
When I do do-release-upgrade, I get a message saying it has aborted the process.
Anyone else having this problem?
This is the message I get:
Could not calculate the upgrade
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
The package 'update-manager' is marked for removal but it is in the
removal deny list.
If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
Restoring original system state
Aborting

Insufficient data. Your question should show us complete output.


Remove the old update-manager "sudo apt remove update-manager".
Install the update-manager again "sudo apt install update-manager".

